# Связь int и char C++

Tags: c++, char

Здраствуйте! Проводил несколько опытов, и увидел, что когда читаешь цифру из чаровой строки, то число ровно на 48 больше чем эта цифра. Правда ли это, и почему?

Comment: Конкретный пример.

Comment: 48 - это код нуля. Наверное вы путаете число, и символьный код таблицы АSCII.

Comment: В "чаровой строке" хранятся символы, а не цифры. Цифра `9` и символ `9` - совершенно разные вещи.

Comment: **На практике** да. В теории можно допустить существование кодировки, в которой цифры сопоставлены другим кодам, но я таких не встречал.

Comment: [Потому что числа - это не строки](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988).

Comment: А когда это цифры перестали быть символами?

Answer (score 5):

Посмотрите таблицу символов ASCII.

В этой таблице можно увидеть, как каждый символ представляется числом. Для буквы 'a' это 97, а для '0' - 48. Соответственно, '1' - 49 и т.д.

Сам же тип `char` обычно имеет размер 1 байт с диапазоном значений от -128 до 127, что позволяет хранить один символ. Конкретные диапазон значений и размер зависят от платформы.

Comment: "диапазон его значений составляет от -128 до 127" - на это лучше не полагаться, ибо стандартом не гарантируется.

Comment: char бывает signed и unsiged. это зависит от конфигурации. Ещё, если мы unsigned присваиваем signed - то знак может терятся.

Comment: *что позволяет хранить один символ*... только не любой символ и не любой кодировки. Столь любимый нами UTF-8 кодирует кириллицу двухбайтовыми codepoint'ами, к примеру.

Comment: @D-side, не стоит так углубляться, человек только начал изучать язык. Думаю, он вообще не в курсе что такое UTF-8

Comment: @Иван наверняка, и именно поэтому столь общие утверждения для него особенно опасны. Можно уточнить, что речь об однобайтовых кодировках. Захочет -- выяснит, что они такое :)

Comment: @D-side вопрос был очевидно про ASCII

Comment: @Иван неизвестно даже, знал ли автор про ASCII на момент написания вопроса. Нет, не очевидно :)

Comment: А терятся – это что делает?

Answer (score 1):

Правда то, что  `int('1' - '0') == 1`.  Какое значение имеет символ '0', зависит от реализации. Т.е. можно инициализировать строку символами_цифрами следующим образом

```
string s(10, ' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        s[i] = ('0' + i); //'0', '1'... ( isdigit(s[i]) == true; )
```

а вот инициализация следующим образом:

```
for (int i = 48, j = 0; j < 10; ++i, ++j)
        s[j] = char(i);
```

не является переносимым кодом

Comment: пожалуйста, если вы поставили минус, напишите причину его.

Comment: @Alexcei Shmakov, многие не понимают, что тут главное не минусы и плюсы, а главное выразить свое мнение, в попытке довести до читателья  разумную информацию

Answer (score 0):

Любой символ имеет свой код, эти коды сведены в кодовые таблицы. Стандарт (или спецификация?) на определённую кодировку гарантирует вполне определённое соответствие. Но стандарт языка кодировку не предписывает, в лучшем случае она может быть закреплена в документации на какую-то программу, в том числе, на операционную систему. Но даже в этом случае другая программа может работать со своей таблицей. Например, в прошивке спектрума зашита вполне определённая кодировка, но играм даже для спектрума Клайв Синклер не указ, имена файлов все в той кодировке, которая зашита в прошивку, а внутренне представление символов в играх может быть хоть Кои-8, в которой латиница, цифры, пробел и знаки препинания кодируются как в ASCII, но вся кириллица кодируется по-своему, хоть EBCDIC, в которой по-своему закодированы и цифры тоже (0 кодируется числом 240),
стандарты языков об этом молчат. Код цифры больше числа, состоящего из одной этой цифры, ровно на код цифры 0 в том и только в том случае, если все цифры следуют подряд в порядке увеличения своих значений, что в общем случае не гарантировано. Сравнивать же код с самой цифрой нельзя, так как код – число, а цифра – нет. Ну и код самой цифры 0 в неизвестной кодировке теоретически может быть любым, а практически читайте таблицы и узнавайте кодировки для конкретных случаев. Конкретно в ASCII цифры следуют подряд в порядке увеличения своих значений, а 0 кодируется числом 48, но навязать её Вам нельзя.